# How to optimize the computing speed of this for loop?

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, parallel-processing, scientific-computing

I am kind of stuck with a difficult problem (for me, at least). I noticed when profiling my code that nearly all my (single core) computing time was eaten up by the single nested loop below (double integral on an image). What do you think would be the best way to accelerate its computing?

I tried to map it to nested streams, but I do not understand how to map the multiple `if` blocks... Would trying to do it on the GPU using OpenCL be better suited to the problem?

`ip` is an ImageJ `ImageProcessor`, and its method `.getPixelValue(x,y)` is also quite ressource consuming. But since it belongs to an established lib, I would like to avoid modifying it if I can.

#### Variables declarations:

```
private ImageProcessor ip = null; //This type comes from ImageJ
private double area;
private double a11, a22;
private double u1, u2;
private double v1, v2;
private double y1, y2;
private static final double HALF_SQRT2 = sqrt(2.0) / 2.0;
private static final double SQRT_TINY =
    sqrt((double)Float.intBitsToFloat((int)0x33FFFFFF));
```

---

#### Function:

```
private double contrast (
) {
    if (area < 1.0) {
        return(1.0 / SQRT_TINY);
    }
    double c = 0.0;
    final int xmin = max((int)floor(u1), 0);
    final int xmax = min((int)ceil(v1), width - 1);
    final int ymin = max((int)floor(u2), 0);
    final int ymax = min((int)ceil(v2), height - 1);
    if ((u1 < xmin) || (xmax < v1) || (u2 < ymin) || (ymax < v2)){
        return(1.0 / SQRT_TINY);
    }
    if ((xmax <= xmin) || (ymax <= ymin)) {
        return(1.0 / SQRT_TINY);
    }
    for (int y = ymin; (y <= ymax); y++) {
        final double dy = y2 - (double)y;
        final double dy2 = dy * dy;
        for (int x = xmin; (x <= xmax); x++) {
            final double dx = y1 - (double)x;
            final double dx2 = dx * dx;
            final double d = sqrt(dx2 + dy2);
            double z = a11 * dx2 + a12 * dx * dy + a22 * dy2;
            if (z < SQRT_TINY) {
                c -= ip.getPixelValue(x, y);
                continue;
            }
            z = a3 / sqrt(z);
            double d0 = (1.0 - z / SQRT2) * d;
            if (d0 < -HALF_SQRT2) {
                c -= ip.getPixelValue(x, y);
                continue;
            }
            if (d0 < HALF_SQRT2) {
                c += SQRT2 * d0 * ip.getPixelValue(x, y);
                continue;
            }
            d0 = (1.0 - z) * d;
            if (d0 < -1.0) {
                c += ip.getPixelValue(x, y);
                continue;
            }
            if (d0 < 1.0) {
                c += (1.0 - d0) * ip.getPixelValue(x, y) / 2.0;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    return(c / area);
```

Comment: Don't know how to help you with speeding up the code but your code could have some extra parenthesis reduced. No need for extra parenthesis see operator precedence http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html 
    `if (u1 < xmin || xmax < v1 || u2 < ymin || ymax < v2)`. See Java Coding Convention (section 7.3), you should stick with no parenthesis in `return c / area;` Good luck!:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try a **divide and conquer** approach.

Divide the image into **n** parts, that are processed in parallel.
But you have to handle the edge cases that occur on the borders (where two parts meet).

Or you could start looking for numeric algorithms, which compute (discrete) integrals and were designed for parallelism.

**Update**

Since your method is called `contrast`, I assume you're changing the contrast of the image.

Operations on images can be performed via convolution (which is essentially a discrete double integral, if performed on a 2D image) with a specific [kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28image_processing%29) (image filter). These operations can be computed on the GPU and yield speed-ups by orders of magnitude. You can use [OpenCl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) to write programs that execute on several GPUs.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given too much info on what is going on here in the loop, for example, what is the variable 'ip'. But in general, I would recommend instantiating the variables outside the scope of the for-loop, as the use of local variables increase memory usage

Comment: Yes, you're right. I added the variable declarations to my question.